# How do I obtain (recreate) the bearer token used in AzureDevOps Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-automation, dsc

I have a failed yaml Infrastructure-as-Code deployment that is failing at the first yaml step:

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@1
  displayName: 'Archive createADPDC.ps1 DSC files '
  inputs:
    rootFolder: 'Core/Templates/createADPDC.ps1'
    includeRootFolder: false
    replaceExistingArchive: true
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/createADPDC.ps1.zip'
```

To troubleshoot this, I've started a line-by-line attempt to simulate what's being done on the hosted pipeline servers, and am getting stuck at the bearer token. Unless there is a better way to diagnose why files are missing from `ArtifactStagingDirectory`, I'm running the commands below to inspect the files and structure that's being downloaded.

```
git init "C:\a\1\s"
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/a/1/s/.git/
git remote add origin https://MyLabs@dev.azure.com/MyLabs/Core/_git/Core
git config gc.auto 0
git config --get-all http.https://MyLabs@dev.azure.com/MyLabs/Core/_git/Core.extraheader
git config --get-all http.proxy                                                                            
git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://dev.azure.com/MyLabs/Core/_git/Core/'
```

**Question**

Either:

1. What is a better way to determine or understand why the ArchiveFiles would return

> [error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\a\1\s\Core\Templates\createADPDC.ps1'

2. What is the correct way to obtain the bearer token (PAT?) for use in the command line located in the logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's probably a good idea to get a handle on the directory structure used within the pipeline.

- `\agent_work\1` $(Agent.BuildDirectory)

  - `\agent_work\1\a` $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  - `\agent_work\1\b` $(Build.BinariesDirectory)
  - `\agent_work\1\s` $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

---

- $(Agent.BuildDirectory) `where all folders for a given build pipeline are created`

  - $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) `artifacts are copied to before being pushed to their destination.`
  - $(Build.BinariesDirectory) `you can use as an output folder for compiled binaries`
  - $(Build.SourcesDirectory) `where your source code files are downloaded`

---

Links for [Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables) and [SystemAccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken)

---

From the error message, it looks like the `rootFolder` location is relative to the `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`. To get a good look at your files inside the `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)` I like to use the `tree` command.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: tree $(Agent.BuildDirectory)
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'tree /F'
    pwsh: true
    workingDirectory: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)'
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you sure the directory is correct?
2. You can access the PAT in pipeline scripts by using $(system.accesstoken).
   Make sure you enable persistcredentials at the job level in your yml